# How to get both div to be the same height

Tags: html, css

I have a website where I need the main page and the right panel div elements to be the same height.

This is the markup I got so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">

* 
{
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
}

body, form, html {
    height:             100%;
}
html
{
    font-family:        helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:          13px;
    margin:             0px;
    padding:            0px;
    background-color:   #f4f4f4;
}

.wrapper 
{
    min-height:         100%;
    height:             auto !important;
    height:             100%;
    margin:             0 auto -140px;
}

#header
{
    background:         url("Images/backgrounds/headback_50x50.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top;
    width:              100%;
    margin-top:         0px;
    height:             50px;
    background-color:   #474747;

}
#header .content {
    width:              100%;
    max-width:          1000px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
}
#header #mainMenu {
    float:              left;
    margin-left:        50px;
    margin-top:         23px;
}
#mainContent
{

    background-repeat:  repeat-y;
    width:              1006px;
    padding:            10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:   #f4f4f4;
    min-height:         100%;
    height:             auto !important;
    height:             100%;
    margin:             0 auto;
}
#mainContent #page {
    width:              800px;
    float:              left;
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius:     4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius:          4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

#mainContent #rightPanel {
    width:              196px;
    overflow:           visible;
    float:              left;
    margin-left:        10px;
    height:             1000px;
}

#mainContent #rightPanel #rightCon {
    background-color:   #ffffff;
    padding:            7px;
    -moz-border-radius:     4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius:          4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
#footer
{
    background:         url("Images/backgrounds/footerback_300x300.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top;
    width:              100%;
    margin:             0px;
    height:             200px;
    background-color:   #3d3d3d;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="contentBody">
                        <div class="mainLogo">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div id="mainMenu">

                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="mainContent">
                <div id="page">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et molestie diam viverra sed proin, nec aenean. Vel donec donec, luctus donec elementum sed. Tristique arcu ut mauris quam potenti in. Mauris velit ut torquent, sagittis et, mi tellus tincidunt elit posuere. Enim aliquam quam sociosqu wisi. Dignissim blandit id. Praesent donec, pellentesque nulla.
Integer aliquam tincidunt sapien neque nec, auctor lacinia nullam lectus dolor. Vehicula litora vel lacinia, auctor ultricies, lacus orci ligula leo eros, turpis vel repellendus erat felis totam suscipit, nulla magnis justo wisi inceptos. A tortor eget quis massa vitae mauris, urna lorem auctor congue, aliquam pellentesque at, quis enim id platea ipsum et. Lectus mauris, hac sit vestibulum diam nam, massa laoreet arcu tincidunt sagittis malesuada mattis, velit in lacus augue quisque, quam eget dolor et. Nostrud nec, urna natoque, turpis a, mauris id viverra id. Sit posuere, ut placerat, ac tempus nulla consectetuer. Sit fames quam morbi proin ut, mi massa, justo erat at curae tellus dignissim non, viverra sodales egestas imperdiet molestie faucibus mauris, morbi massa enim non.
Nec massa. Libero ornare est magnis, placerat ipsum justo ut in penatibus tortor, libero rutrum incididunt vehicula, elit elit accumsan donec. Urna auctor nonummy arcu, mi vivamus enim dis eu, etiam cursus faucibus quam eu, neque ipsum, ultrices enim. Laoreet mollis vestibulum, ut lacus ante ipsum. Hymenaeos sapien ut at, non wisi ipsum magna sed et justo, nulla adipiscing quis eget et feugiat diam, justo malesuada curabitur, aliquet ac condimentum quisque justo duis tortor. Vestibulum in semper turpis scelerisque diam, egestas magna dolorum, est consequat velit consectetuer tempus, orci est. Netus amet, eos rutrum lacus, nec ad sed ipsum tortor mattis tincidunt, et eget ut auctor aliquam sollicitudin diam, ornare elit pede cursus ornare elit ante. Suspendisse suspendisse sem justo, erat dictum elementum volutpat vel urna a. Vestibulum sodales, vel ut massa sapien orci, luctus provident iaculis, lorem libero ut et in, at ante felis. Maecenas praesent in. Justo ut sollicitudin magnis vitae morbi, auctor malesuada vel vestibulum vitae, in risus elit mi, facilisi suscipit congue volutpat nisi et, pretium lacus.
Velit amet vel praesent id, elit duis bibendum pharetra phasellus eget sit, nibh consequat, justo magna vestibulum vestibulum. Vitae elit tortor adipiscing aliquam, sit elit fringilla velit tincidunt in risus, aenean sem lectus phasellus mattis volutpat quis. Sem vehicula lorem id eros nullam, at proin in. Wisi dictum imperdiet, nunc gravida nibh, pellentesque tellus aliquam diam culpa sit amet, porro pede risus volutpat faucibus ut libero, viverra donec. Fringilla mauris duis mauris turpis nam. Ante pellentesque, fusce lacus vitae lacus tincidunt, laoreet eget, vel faucibus amet vel. Eleifend cras et fermentum pharetra, justo porta, sapien amet nullam habitant dolor curabitur et, id eu sit. Vitae at, in et. Convallis rutrum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et molestie diam viverra sed proin, nec aenean. Vel donec donec, luctus donec elementum sed. Tristique arcu ut mauris quam potenti in. Mauris velit ut torquent, sagittis et, mi tellus tincidunt elit posuere. Enim aliquam quam sociosqu wisi. Dignissim blandit id. Praesent donec, pellentesque nulla.
Integer aliquam tincidunt sapien neque nec, auctor lacinia nullam lectus dolor. Vehicula litora vel lacinia, auctor ultricies, lacus orci ligula leo eros, turpis vel repellendus erat felis totam suscipit, nulla magnis justo wisi inceptos. A tortor eget quis massa vitae mauris, urna lorem auctor congue, aliquam pellentesque at, quis enim id platea ipsum et. Lectus mauris, hac sit vestibulum diam nam, massa laoreet arcu tincidunt sagittis malesuada mattis, velit in lacus augue quisque, quam eget dolor et. Nostrud nec, urna natoque, turpis a, mauris id viverra id. Sit posuere, ut placerat, ac tempus nulla consectetuer. Sit fames quam morbi proin ut, mi massa, justo erat at curae tellus dignissim non, viverra sodales egestas imperdiet molestie faucibus mauris, morbi massa enim non.
Nec massa. Libero ornare est magnis, placerat ipsum justo ut in penatibus tortor, libero rutrum incididunt vehicula, elit elit accumsan donec. Urna auctor nonummy arcu, mi vivamus enim dis eu, etiam cursus faucibus quam eu, neque ipsum, ultrices enim. Laoreet mollis vestibulum, ut lacus ante ipsum. Hymenaeos sapien ut at, non wisi ipsum magna sed et justo, nulla adipiscing quis eget et feugiat diam, justo malesuada curabitur, aliquet ac condimentum quisque justo duis tortor. Vestibulum in semper turpis scelerisque diam, egestas magna dolorum, est consequat velit consectetuer tempus, orci est. Netus amet, eos rutrum lacus, nec ad sed ipsum tortor mattis tincidunt, et eget ut auctor aliquam sollicitudin diam, ornare elit pede cursus ornare elit ante. Suspendisse suspendisse sem justo, erat dictum elementum volutpat vel urna a. Vestibulum sodales, vel ut massa sapien orci, luctus provident iaculis, lorem libero ut et in, at ante felis. Maecenas praesent in. Justo ut sollicitudin magnis vitae morbi, auctor malesuada vel vestibulum vitae, in risus elit mi, facilisi suscipit congue volutpat nisi et, pretium lacus.
Velit amet vel praesent id, elit duis bibendum pharetra phasellus eget sit, nibh consequat, justo magna vestibulum vestibulum. Vitae elit tortor adipiscing aliquam, sit elit fringilla velit tincidunt in risus, aenean sem lectus phasellus mattis volutpat quis. Sem vehicula lorem id eros nullam, at proin in. Wisi dictum imperdiet, nunc gravida nibh, pellentesque tellus aliquam diam culpa sit amet, porro pede risus volutpat faucibus ut libero, viverra donec. Fringilla mauris duis mauris turpis nam. Ante pellentesque, fusce lacus vitae lacus tincidunt, laoreet eget, vel faucibus amet vel. Eleifend cras et fermentum pharetra, justo porta, sapien amet nullam habitant dolor curabitur et, id eu sit. Vitae at, in et. Convallis rutrum.

                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et molestie diam viverra sed proin, nec aenean. Vel donec donec, luctus donec elementum sed. Tristique arcu ut mauris quam potenti in. Mauris velit ut torquent, sagittis et, mi tellus tincidunt elit posuere. Enim aliquam quam sociosqu wisi. Dignissim blandit id. Praesent donec, pellentesque nulla.
Integer aliquam tincidunt sapien neque nec, auctor lacinia nullam lectus dolor. Vehicula litora vel lacinia, auctor ultricies, lacus orci ligula leo eros, turpis vel repellendus erat felis totam suscipit, nulla magnis justo wisi inceptos. A tortor eget quis massa vitae mauris, urna lorem auctor congue, aliquam pellentesque at, quis enim id platea ipsum et. Lectus mauris, hac sit vestibulum diam nam, massa laoreet arcu tincidunt sagittis malesuada mattis, velit in lacus augue quisque, quam eget dolor et. Nostrud nec, urna natoque, turpis a, mauris id viverra id. Sit posuere, ut placerat, ac tempus nulla consectetuer. Sit fames quam morbi proin ut, mi massa, justo erat at curae tellus dignissim non, viverra sodales egestas imperdiet molestie faucibus mauris, morbi massa enim non.
Nec massa. Libero ornare est magnis, placerat ipsum justo ut in penatibus tortor, libero rutrum incididunt vehicula, elit elit accumsan donec. Urna auctor nonummy arcu, mi vivamus enim dis eu, etiam cursus faucibus quam eu, neque ipsum, ultrices enim. Laoreet mollis vestibulum, ut lacus ante ipsum. Hymenaeos sapien ut at, non wisi ipsum magna sed et justo, nulla adipiscing quis eget et feugiat diam, justo malesuada curabitur, aliquet ac condimentum quisque justo duis tortor. Vestibulum in semper turpis scelerisque diam, egestas magna dolorum, est consequat velit consectetuer tempus, orci est. Netus amet, eos rutrum lacus, nec ad sed ipsum tortor mattis tincidunt, et eget ut auctor aliquam sollicitudin diam, ornare elit pede cursus ornare elit ante. Suspendisse suspendisse sem justo, erat dictum elementum volutpat vel urna a. Vestibulum sodales, vel ut massa sapien orci, luctus provident iaculis, lorem libero ut et in, at ante felis. Maecenas praesent in. Justo ut sollicitudin magnis vitae morbi, auctor malesuada vel vestibulum vitae, in risus elit mi, facilisi suscipit congue volutpat nisi et, pretium lacus.
Velit amet vel praesent id, elit duis bibendum pharetra phasellus eget sit, nibh consequat, justo magna vestibulum vestibulum. Vitae elit tortor adipiscing aliquam, sit elit fringilla velit tincidunt in risus, aenean sem lectus phasellus mattis volutpat quis. Sem vehicula lorem id eros nullam, at proin in. Wisi dictum imperdiet, nunc gravida nibh, pellentesque tellus aliquam diam culpa sit amet, porro pede risus volutpat faucibus ut libero, viverra donec. Fringilla mauris duis mauris turpis nam. Ante pellentesque, fusce lacus vitae lacus tincidunt, laoreet eget, vel faucibus amet vel. Eleifend cras et fermentum pharetra, justo porta, sapien amet nullam habitant dolor curabitur et, id eu sit. Vitae at, in et. Convallis rutrum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et molestie diam viverra sed proin, nec aenean. Vel donec donec, luctus donec elementum sed. Tristique arcu ut mauris quam potenti in. Mauris velit ut torquent, sagittis et, mi tellus tincidunt elit posuere. Enim aliquam quam sociosqu wisi. Dignissim blandit id. Praesent donec, pellentesque nulla.
Integer aliquam tincidunt sapien neque nec, auctor lacinia nullam lectus dolor. Vehicula litora vel lacinia, auctor ultricies, lacus orci ligula leo eros, turpis vel repellendus erat felis totam suscipit, nulla magnis justo wisi inceptos. A tortor eget quis massa vitae mauris, urna lorem auctor congue, aliquam pellentesque at, quis enim id platea ipsum et. Lectus mauris, hac sit vestibulum diam nam, massa laoreet arcu tincidunt sagittis malesuada mattis, velit in lacus augue quisque, quam eget dolor et. Nostrud nec, urna natoque, turpis a, mauris id viverra id. Sit posuere, ut placerat, ac tempus nulla consectetuer. Sit fames quam morbi proin ut, mi massa, justo erat at curae tellus dignissim non, viverra sodales egestas imperdiet molestie faucibus mauris, morbi massa enim non.
Nec massa. Libero ornare est magnis, placerat ipsum justo ut in penatibus tortor, libero rutrum incididunt vehicula, elit elit accumsan donec. Urna auctor nonummy arcu, mi vivamus enim dis eu, etiam cursus faucibus quam eu, neque ipsum, ultrices enim. Laoreet mollis vestibulum, ut lacus ante ipsum. Hymenaeos sapien ut at, non wisi ipsum magna sed et justo, nulla adipiscing quis eget et feugiat diam, justo malesuada curabitur, aliquet ac condimentum quisque justo duis tortor. Vestibulum in semper turpis scelerisque diam, egestas magna dolorum, est consequat velit consectetuer tempus, orci est. Netus amet, eos rutrum lacus, nec ad sed ipsum tortor mattis tincidunt, et eget ut auctor aliquam sollicitudin diam, ornare elit pede cursus ornare elit ante. Suspendisse suspendisse sem justo, erat dictum elementum volutpat vel urna a. Vestibulum sodales, vel ut massa sapien orci, luctus provident iaculis, lorem libero ut et in, at ante felis. Maecenas praesent in. Justo ut sollicitudin magnis vitae morbi, auctor malesuada vel vestibulum vitae, in risus elit mi, facilisi suscipit congue volutpat nisi et, pretium lacus.
Velit amet vel praesent id, elit duis bibendum pharetra phasellus eget sit, nibh consequat, justo magna vestibulum vestibulum. Vitae elit tortor adipiscing aliquam, sit elit fringilla velit tincidunt in risus, aenean sem lectus phasellus mattis volutpat quis. Sem vehicula lorem id eros nullam, at proin in. Wisi dictum imperdiet, nunc gravida nibh, pellentesque tellus aliquam diam culpa sit amet, porro pede risus volutpat faucibus ut libero, viverra donec. Fringilla mauris duis mauris turpis nam. Ante pellentesque, fusce lacus vitae lacus tincidunt, laoreet eget, vel faucibus amet vel. Eleifend cras et fermentum pharetra, justo porta, sapien amet nullam habitant dolor curabitur et, id eu sit. Vitae at, in et. Convallis rutrum.
                </div>
                <div id="rightPanel">
                    <div id="rightCon">
                        Right Panel
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="content">
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to see what's going on if you would create a fiddle.

Comment: So you want you right content to be the same height of the left content?

Comment: Can you have a look **[on this jsFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/Mee3/zBdDX/)**

Comment: @Mee, the right panel is not exact the same height?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić there is a fiddle?

Comment: @SnowJim humm.. strange. On mine they show as the same height :/

Comment: @Mee Im using Chrome where the diff is some pixels and in IE(latest) its a lot of diff.

Comment: @SnowJim im using Chrome as well. You didn't mention that you wanted it for IE. So have you tried `Display: table-cell` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: table-cell` is a simple and reliable solution for this kind of problem. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/26MGE/

Comment: This looks nice, is it safe to use even for mobile devices? Could you pleas modify my fiddle to show that its possible in that setup as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TMxGL/ you don't need any float, relative, javascript or any confusing stuff anymore.

Comment: This behaviour is so normal because you're using `height: 100%` and `overflow: visible`

Comment: in addition, you should remove `margin` of `.wrapper`

Comment: I see that you have placed the rounded background on the page class instead? This is not good. The design is that every "part" have there own white panel, just like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margins to set up divs with equal height;

**CSS**

```
#container {
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
float:left;
width:700px;
border-left: 260px solid #555;
}

#sidebar {
float: left;
width:260px;
margin-right: -260px;
position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Main content</p>
</div>

</div>
```

This is a really effective way to achieve a same height column effect. You could also check out some other ways to achieve this, which may be better suited to your needs.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

I am sure that implementing it into the code you have given should be a not so hard of a task, so I will leave it with you.

Good luck with your site!

Comment: This looks like vertical centering styling. Can you demonstrate this with OP's HTML please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use jQuery, it'd be much more easier when you just need:

```
$("#rightCon").height($('#page').height());
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UAguW/)**

Comment: Problem with this solution is that if you fill the right panel with even more date the page will not follow right panel.